# Why generate scaffold won't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I'm currently following Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl [here.](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app)

To proceed with my application I did the following(as the book said):

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

However I'm getting the following errors:

[image]

Comment: Show your application.js requires block and sass-rails version

Comment: Firstly, please do not post pictures of your log. Instead, copy and paste the log directly to your question. Second, please find your `application.js` file and edit your question to include its full contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite strange, but i'd say you should probably run `bundle install` again. If that doesn't resolve it, then you should add to your Gemfile:

`gem 'sass'`